# Add Banner Below Menu in Category Page

Tags: magento

I need to add the category banner below the Breadcrumbs.

I have tried by adding new reference

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_banner') ?>
```

in the 2columns-left.phtml 
and in local.xml

```
    <catalog_category_view>
                     <reference name="category_banner">
                    <block type="core/template" name="topbanner" template="catalog/category/category-image.phtml" before="-"></block>
                 </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
     <catalog_category_default translate="label">
                <reference name="category_banner">
                    <block type="core/template" name="banner" template="catalog/category/category-image.phtml"></block>
                 </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

But output is not coming.

Comment: 2 things. First one you are calling with wrong name in getChildHtml in your xml file you add a block with the name "topbanner" and you are asking for "category_banner". Second, you have an inconsistent in your code, you add a getChildHtml under root template and in your xml you reference to content. Change your reference value to root and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added new line inside the all layout i.e 2columns-left.phtml etc.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_banner') ?>
```

added below line inside your xml

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
       <block type="core/template" name="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category-image.phtml" before="-"></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```